# JQuery Avoid Null in URL?

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering if there's any way I can avoid parameter=null in jsp?

Will there be any function that's similar to the [Java's ? : operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html) for Jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional Operators or Ternary Operators are the term you are looking for... and to clarify jQuery is a library built on top of the Javascript programming language. Conditional operators exist as part of the language and not the framework.

you can read more about them here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator